# How to convert ExpandableListActivity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, android-actionbaractivity

I am looking for a good sample I can reference for using an expandable list backed by a database in a fragment, so I can use it with ActionBarActivity. I saw this post:

[Android - Expandable List within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072683/android-expandable-list-within-fragments)

but don't understand fully how the DBHelper works so a sample I could import into Android Studio would be ideal. Thanks in advance.